# how to do responsive with css grid and reversed order of elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an html code with two éléments and I would like to invert them on responsive, like so :

[image]

Is it possible in css or must I do it in js ?
(sorry if bad english)

Comment: Why don't just use a simple `float:left` for both elements, putting both of them inside a `div` with `width='100%'`... once the device is smaller... it will automatically move

Comment: that's what I did for the desktop, it works as well, BUT in mobile, since the "element 2" is placed after element 1 (cf html code) it will be placed after element 1, and that's not what I want.

Comment: use twitter bootstrap

Comment: It is definitely possible in CSS, but not straightforward, with any of the options (grid, flex, floats, inline-blocks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use display flex and order like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>element 1</div>
   <div>element 2</div>
</div>

.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }


 .container div:nth-child(1){
   order:2;
 }

 .container div:nth-child(2){
   order:1;
 }

//change the 1024px for you desktop size target
@media (min-width:1024px){

 .container div:nth-child(1){
   order:1;
 }

 .container div:nth-child(2){
   order:2;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent approach!, you just need to fix `.container:nth-child(0)` to `.container div:nth-child(0)`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! I just had to add "flax-direction: column" for the mobile version (and implement Shadi Shaaban's comment) and it worked fine !

Comment: I will add the changes, sorry when I answer before, I was in my mobile and answered from memory, did not review before posting it. Changes updated.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

If your elements have known width and height, you could achieve that using direction:rtl and display:inline-block for both elements and @media queries with absolute positioning on smaller screens, **see demo**: http://jsbin.com/wufuwibuhe/edit?html,css,output

```css
#container{
  direction:rtl;
  text-align:left;
}

element{
  width:250px; 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block; 
  direction:ltr; // restore direction   inside element
}

@media (max-width:530px){
  #container{                  
    height:210px;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  element{    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
  }
  
  element:first-of-type{  
    top:auto; 
    bottom: 0;
  }

}
```

```html
  <h1>Resize me!</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <element first-of-type>1</element>
     <element>2</element>
  </div>
```

Comment: that would have been a solution if the element 1 was first, but my problem is i can not place element 1 first, I need to put it after element 2 (my problem is complicated ><) but thanks !

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer with another approach using direction:rtl on normal screens and absolute positioning on smaller screens, however this will require that your elements to have width/height set, hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I've implemented T04435's solution with your comments, I'll try your updated solution when I have more time, thanks a lot again !

Comment: Always good to advise answer with Mobile First in mind so the CSS with no @ media around it will target the mobiles and then you use @ media for Tablet and Desktop. use *@ media all and (min-width)*

Comment: @T04435 Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Your specific problem is described here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering